# How to compare and add elements of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, equality

I'd like to take a single array lets say 3x5 as follows

```
1 3 5
1 3 5
2 8 6
4 5 7
4 5 8
```

and write a code that will create a new array that adds the third column together with the previous number if the numbers in the first and second columns equal the numbers in the row below it.

since the first two values in row 1 and 2, then add the third elements in row 1 and 2 together

so the output from the array above should look like this

```
1 3 10
2 8 6
4 5 15
```

Comment: What does your attempt at coding your problem look like? Please give an example of what you tried.

Comment: Does the order matters ? Are the value sorted ? And what happens if there is not 2 but 3 pair of value ?

Answer (score 3):

The function `accumarray(subs,val)` accumulate elements of vector val using the subscripts subs. So we can use this function to sum the elements in the third column having the same value in the first and second column. We can use `unique(...,'rows')` to determine which pairs of value are unique.

```
%Example data
A = [1 3 5,
     1 3 5,
     2 3 6,
     4 5 7,
     4 5 7]

%Get the unique pair of value based on the first two column (uni) and the associated index.
[uni,~,sub] = unique(A(:,1:2),'rows');

%Create the result using accumarray.
R = [uni, accumarray(sub,A(:,3))]
```

**If the orders matters** the script would be a little bit more complex:

```
%Get the unique pair of value based on the first two column (uni) and the associated index.
[uni,~,sub] = unique(A(:,1:2),'rows');

%Locate the consecutive similar row with this small tricks
dsub = diff([0;sub])~=0;

%Create the adjusted index
subo = cumsum(dsub);

%Create the new array
R = [uni(sub(dsub),:), accumarray(subo,A(:,3))]
```

Or you can get an identical result with a for loop:

```
R = A(1,:)
for ii = 2:length(A)
    if all(A(ii-1,1:2)==A(ii,1:2))
        R(end,3) = R(end,3)+A(ii,3)
    else
        R(end+1,:) = A(ii,:)
    end
end
```

**Benchmark:**

With an array A of size `100000x3` on the mathworks live editor:

The for loop take about `5.5s` (no pre-allocation, so it's pretty slow)

The vectorized method take about `0.012s`

Comment: Thank you! i never would have figured that out